# Python, Script to run all test scripts in directory

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-unittest

I'm trying to create a script that will run all of my test files from a directory.

```
project folder
Test_one.py
Test_two.py
Test_three.py
...
Test_ten.py
```

Looking to create a file call "run_test.py" that will execute this.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple python script to do this.

```py
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
for file in files:
    if file.startswith("Test") and file.endswith(".py") and not os.path.isdir(file):
        os.system("python3 " + file)
```

Comment: That's a good start for me. Thanks!